# Create a new table (copy of an existing) with date order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (table1) that the column `dateColmn` is not with an asc or desc order. I want to create a new one-copy of the table1- (lets say table2) with date order. The purpose of this action is to use the diagramm mode in the phpmyadmin  with the right date order.
I have this code but unfortunatelly it doesn't create the table2 as I expected...It copy the table1 as it is...

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` LIKE `table1`;
INSERT INTO `table2` SELECT * FROM `table1` ORDER BY `dateColmn` DESC;
```

How I can solve this?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering in a table, so something is amiss in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not insert into the table instead create copy of the table as it is. Below query will help you to get the data in sorted order,

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS SELECT * FROM table1 order by datacolumn desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets.  Period.  If you want a result set in a particular order, *you have to use an `ORDER BY` clause*:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM `table1` t1
ORDER BY `dateColmn` DESC;
```

If you want to speed this up, create an index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_table1_dateColumn ON table1(datecolumn DESC);
```

(The most recent versions of MySQL even understand the `DESC` ordering.)